# Adding Newly Created Items To An Inventory Using .push_back

Tags: c++, class, function, vector

all! I am in the process of creating an inventory class. Here's what I have for the implementation file so far:

```
//aItem .cpp implementation file

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "aitem.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//setting this up default
aItem::aItem()
{
    vector<aItem> inventory;
    mitemName = "Default Name";
    mitemType = "Default Type";
    mdamage  = 9001;
}

void aItem::ItemList()
{
    for( vector<aItem>::size_type index = 0; index < inventory.size(); index++ ) 
        {
            //Makes a numerical list.
            cout << "Item " << index + 1 << ": " <<  inventory[index].mitemName << endl;
            index+= 1;
        }
}

void aItem::ItemAdd(string itemName, string itemType, int damage)
{
    mitemName = itemName;
    mitemType = itemType;
    mdamage = damage;

    inventory.push_back
```

The abrupt cut in the middle of ItemAdd() is my problem. If I don't have it pulling from a list where I know the names, how can I add the newly-created item to my inventory vector?

Comment: It looks like you want to have a class `X` containing a `vector<X>`. This is not possible, since it implies an infinite recursion (each `X` in the vector contains `X` objects, which each contain a `vector<X>`, each of which contain ...

Comment: Your current implementation say *your item has-a inventory*. This logic does not seem right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use m_name instead of mitemName, it's just much easier to read, and more widely used.

Now to your actual problem, you have an inventory called aItem, which holds a vector of aItems... Here's your problem, create a class for item, and a class for inventory (if you need one). They can't be in the same class.

So here I create my item class (I'll call it Item, you can call yours aItem if you prefer), which only controls name, type and damage of the item.

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <string>

class Item {
    public:
        Item();
        virtual ~Item();
        virtual void setName(std::string name);
        virtual std::string getName();
        virtual void setType(std::string type); // consider enum for types here
        virtual std::string getType();
        virtual void setDamage(int damage);
        virtual int getDamage();

    private:
        std::string m_name;
        std::string m_type;
        int m_damage;
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

I suppose you can code the `.cpp` side yourself, that's the header file.

And here's my `Inventory.h`, which again you can rename to match your liking.

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include "item.h"
#include <vector>

class Inventory {
    public:
        Inventory();
        virtual ~Inventory();
        virtual void addItem(Item* item);
        virtual void removeItem(int index); // You could implement removeItem(Item* item); too

    private:
        std::vector<Item*> m_items;
};

#endif // INVENTORY_H
```

Now you can freely implement any methods to either one of those classes, if you ever need anything more.

Comment: Thank you, I'm puzzling through this fairly well, except I don't understand the purpose of "virtual ~Item(); as I am not familiar with "~".

Comment: I suppose you know what constructor `Item::Item()` does. Now `Item::~Item()` is the opposite, it's the class' "destructor" and it gets called whenever the object is destroyed. You can of course leave it out, but you could add a parent attribute (a pointer to the inventory where your item is) to Item class, and that way inside the Item's destructor you could call `m_parent.removeItem(this)` or whatever. However, it's just an optional suggestion, and mostly to help you realize what destructor does.

Answer (score 1):

If your inventory doesn't need to be a class of its own as others have suggested, you could pass it to the item class when it is needed by reference. This is probably not the best way to do it but you wouldn't have to write another class.

Eg.

```
int main(){
    aItem sword("wooden","sword", 5);
    aItem axe("stone", "axe", 15);
    std::vector<aItem> inventory;
    sword.addTo(inventory);
    axe.addTo(inventory);
    ...
```

and in aItem.cpp:

```
void aItem::add(std::vector<aItem> &inventory){
    inventory.push_back(*this);
}
```

Or, you could use pointers instead if you wanted to deal with memory issues instead of scoping issues:

```
int main(){
    aItem* sword = new aItem("wooden","sword", 5);
    aItem* axe = new aItem("stone", "axe", 15);
    std::vector<aItem*> inventory;
    sword->addTo(inventory);
    axe->addTo(inventory);
    ...
```

and in aItem.cpp:

```
void aItem::add(std::vector<aItem*> &inventory){
    inventory.push_back(this);
}
```

But again, an inventory class that properly handles the scoping or memory management would be better than this in almost all cases.

Comment: Of course it doesn't have to be a class, but it should be one. If this is gonna get any more advanced, having one vector is probably not going to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a class called aItem which is supposed to be an "item" and also store the inventory?  Sounds like you need another class for maintaining the inventory which contains the vector of items.

Secondly you have a stack variable as your inventory right now.  As soon as your constructor goes out of scope it is gone.

Lastly, you're going to need to create a temporary "item" to add to the inventory.  That is what gets pushed back;)

Comment: Thank you. As you can tell, I'm very much a newbie just trying to slog through this. Let me give your suggestions a go!